# flex pass data between mxmls

Tags: apache-flex

index.mxml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                initialize="{newfile.send()}" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:Style source="CSS/goodlist.css"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.utils.URLUtil;

            public var jsonStr:String;
            public var jsonArr:Array;


            [Bindable]
            private var catalog:ArrayCollection;
            protected function newfile_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                jsonStr = String(newfile.lastResult);
                jsonArr = JSON.decode(jsonStr) as Array;

                var products:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(jsonArr);
                var temp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                var product:Product;


                for each(var pro:Object in products)
                {
                    product = new Product();
                    product.name = pro.name;
                    product.ID = pro.ID;
                    product.category = pro.category;
                    product.description = pro.description;
                    product.price = pro.price;
                    product.unitID =pro.unitID;
                    product.cutoff = pro.cutoff;
                    product.store = pro.store;
                    product.locationID = pro.locationID;

                    temp.addItem(product);
                }

                catalog = temp;

                show.text = String(catalog.length);

                saleStack._catalog = catalog
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:HTTPService url="http://localhost/newfile.php" id="newfile"
                    result="newfile_resultHandler(event)"
                    method="GET" resultFormat="text">
    </mx:HTTPService>
    <mx:VBox>
        <local:saleView width="100" height="100" id="saleStack" showEffect="WipeDown" hideEffect="WipeUp"/>
        <mx:Label id="show"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

saleView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
         initialize="{this.canvas1_initializeHandler()}">

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import CatalogEvent;
            import Product;


            import flash.utils.Dictionary;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;


            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            private var productCatalog:Array;


            [Bindable]
            public var _catalog:ArrayCollection;


            protected function canvas1_initializeHandler():void
            {
                test.text = String(_catalog);

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="test"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

then test.text shows that"null"

but if delete `test.text = String(_catalog);`
and change the label test like this

```
<mx:Label id="test" text="{_catalog}"/>
```

test will show the _catalog

I don't konw y,I want to use _catalog in many other functions

Please .....

Comment: some more explanation and an actual question might help us understand this some more.

Comment: I voted to close b/c you didn't ask a question.  Please clarify what the issue is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

canvas1_initializeHandler is called once, before _catalog has been set by newfile_resultHandler, so it will be null.

Your other example uses data binding to update the properties when its dependencies change. To get this in ActionScript, use ChangeWatcher or BindingUtils: [Defining data bindings in ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc9.html), or you can create a set function for catalog that handles the updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to use data binding in mentioned example. The changes need to be done in given example is mentioned below.

1. Change
[Bindable]
private var catalog:ArrayCollection;

To 

[Bindable]
public var catalog:ArrayCollection;

2. Change 
 <local:saleView width="100" height="100" id="saleStack"  showEffect="WipeDown" hideEffect="WipeUp"/>

To

<local:saleView width="100" height="100" id="saleStack" _catalog="{catalog}" showEffect="WipeDown" hideEffect="WipeUp"/>

3. Use proper data binding to bind data , that has to be shown in Lable or else where , because in  given example binding will not happen when http call fetches data from server .You need to declare bindable variable and bind it properly with lable. some of this shot

 [Bindable]
 public var _catalog:ArrayCollection;
 [Bindable]
 private var tempStr:String;


            protected function canvas1_initializeHandler():void
            {
                tempStr = String(_catalog);

            }

<mx:Label id="test" text="{tempStr}"/>
```